# Deleting or edititng a listview in visual studio 2010 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have written a code that uses a listview with 5 columns to view some inputs given by user.

Now after entering the data and showing in listview, I want to edit some columns or delete one raw of the listview.

I looked for long time for a solution but I am failed to get an exact answer.
I do not want to use third party programs.

Is there anybody give me a clue to manage ma problem? 
For any comments I really appreciate it!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2890/Using-ListView-control-under-Win-API

Comment: Can we see what you tried to see if it is something that is just a small modification?

Comment: The listview control only supports editing of the label column by default. To enable editing of other columns requires either sub-classing or creating your own edit control.

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to put the data in to your listview? Are you allowed to use other edit controls outside of the listview to perform your desired tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I found that an easy solution for lists that have a modest number of entires is simply to delete the entire listview and rebuild it from scratch for every change. That seems like a lot of wasted effort, but so long as your code only has to work at user-interface speed, it is a straightforward solution.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to enable editing of the columns in the listview.

Comment: @JonathanPotter exactly what I mean. By clicking or whatever is possible.
by clicking on one item user could edit it or by clicking on a raw(selecting) and clicking a button delete a raw.